# How did a @reply in a comment notify a user?

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, comment-replies

According to this MSE FAQ [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019) :

> #### Who can be notified with this feature?
>
> ...
>
> - For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so. Users who have closed or reopened a question without a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote), and **those who bindingly voted, but other users were also involved (e.g. closed by User1, User2, and Moderator) cannot be notified**.

My [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405008/accessibility-concerns-about-stack-overflow#comment823030_405008) on this question [Accessibility concerns about Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405008) should *not* have notified the user I @replied to. I've highlighted the part of the rule that I think applies to this situation. However, the user confirmed that they did in fact get a notification of my comment.

I don't know how or why this happened. Here are some plausible-ish explanations:

1. The user is a Moderator (although that case seems to be covered by the example in the quoted rule).
2. The user has a gold badge which was used in the duplicate closure (although that appears to be covered in the quoted rule as well).
3. A combined effect of 1. and 2.
4. The user (so they claim) voted to close with a different reason than those used by the other close voters.
5. The post is on Meta as opposed to the Main site.

Perhaps this *shouldn't* have happened, and is actually a bug. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Comment notifications for close voters: regression from 2018?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345569)

Comment: @JeanneDark Perfect. That's almost an exact dupe :) It appears to have nothing to do with Meta vs Main at least.